# Rigourous formalism of Hamiltonian mechanics on Manifolds

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, topology

I'm looking for books / articles that provide rigorous formulations of Hamiltonian mechanics on Manifolds. I found the book "Global Formulations of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Dynamics on Manifolds" [1] by Lee, Leok and McClamroch, but I'm looking for more references.

My goal is to study the math behind those formulations and what problems still demand rigorous definitions.

[1] - http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~mleok/pdf/LHDynamics.pdf

Comment: Any book on classical mechanics will deal with it: two examples are 1. Goldstein 2. Gantmacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another good reference:

- "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" by V.I. Arnol'd
  https://www.amazon.com.br/Mathematical-Classical-Mechanics-Graduate-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00HWVUUDW/

Answer (score 0):

Arnold' work is great. The Russian school of writing a textbook. More abstract and more comprehensive is the American "bible" on mathematical mechanics>

Abraham & Marsden, "Foundations of Mechanics".

[https://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Mechanics-2nd-Ralph-Abraham/dp/080530102X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/080530102X)